how to stores error and success data from the first until current operation in dataloader CLI
I have a need to store data from first and current operation in dataloader CLI. How do I configure it in the process-conf.xml file apart from adding a path to save the file. Or do you need to loop using a batch script?
This is my process-conf.xml file:
    <bean id="RDSBox" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
        <description>Upsert RDSBox</description>
        <property name="name" value="RDSBox"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="D:\RDSBox\workingFolder\newRDSBox.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.lastRunOutputDirectory" value="D:\RDSBox\log"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="D:\Application\Consoles\configSandbox\RDSBox.sdl"/>
                <entry key="process.statusOutputDirectory" value="D:\RDSBox\log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="RDS_Box__c"/>
                <entry key="process.outputError" value="D:\RDSBox\errors\ErrorRDSBox.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="D:\RDSBox\loaded\LoadedRDSUpsert.csv"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Box_Key__c"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="upsert"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

